# Jenkins build failing in CI machine

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have installed jenkins in my CI server machine and i am creating a pipeline to build my project. Jenkins build fails saying it couldn't find the path. However i have mentioned my workspace path in my pipeline code. Also i am using SVN as my sub version. Kindly assist. 
    The error i am getting is

```
+ cd var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ProjectDemo/target
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ProjectDemo@tmp/durable-a40648b0/script.sh: line 1: cd: var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ProjectDemo/target: No such file or directory

pipeline {
agent any
 stages {enter code here
        stage('Code Checkout') {
            steps {
                checkout scm
                }
       }

        stage('Build') {
            steps {


sh 'cd var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ProjectDemo/target; mvn clean package'
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: I think you forgot a '/' at the beginning of your path : `/var/lib/...` and not `var/lib/...`.

Comment: @SmartTom there was '/' in the code. i  just missed it while i was copying and pasting here in stackoverflow. however the error was same. No luck :(

Answer (score 1):

The better solution is use the Jenkins' build in Environment Variable `WORKSPACE` which represents the job's workspace where source code resides after cloned from SVN or Git.

```
stage('Build') {
    steps {
       sh '''
          pwd
          ls -l   
          cd ${WORPKSPACE}
          echo $PATH
          mvn clean package
       '''
    }
}
```

Above `pwd` is to print the path of job's workspace folder, `ls -l` is to print out files & folders under job's workspace folder.  You can remove them if the job's workspace folder is your expected work dir.

Comment: i did try as you suggested and i get a different error this time. it says '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ProjectDemo@tmp/durable-1492caf3/script.sh: line 5: mvn: command not found'. which is very weird because maven is actually installed in my CI server machine and i hadnt go this error in my previous iterations. Pls assist

Comment: you can print out the `PATH` environment to see it includes the folder where the mvn resides.